# Starter flash book to understand basics of flash games and how they communicate with backend servers

Tags: flash

I'm looking for a starter flash book to understand basics of flash games and how they communicate with backend servers.

Any recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.friendsofed.com/book.html?isbn=1590594665

http://www.friendsofed.com/book.html?isbn=9781430218210

check their catalog for other titles, friends of ed have published some excellent books for Flash & Actionscript